# Array of strings in ELK and Spring environment

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk

In ELK environment I have a pipeline with statement like this:

```
SELECT id,
       types::text,
FROM example_table
WHERE last_modified_date > :sql_last_value
ORDER BY id DESC
```

and template like this:

```
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "example_records*"
  ],
  "version": 1,
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "@version": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
      "id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "types": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The *types* column has jsonb type (PostgreSQL) and contains value: `["TYPE_1", "TYPE_2"]`.

I would like to read records from `example_table` by Spring application, in which I have a class

```
@Document(indexName = "example_records", createIndex = false)
@Data
public class ElasticExampleRecord {
    @Id
    @Field(name = "id")
    private final Long id;

    @Field(name = "types")
    private final List<ExampleType> types;
}
```

but I get this data as list of strings, in which at the 0 index is array like `["TYPE_1", "TYPE_2"]`:

```
result.types.size() == 1
result.types.get(0) == "["TYPE_1", "TYPE_2"]".
```

I tried to remove `::text` casting in SQL statement but I got error

```
MissingConverterException: Missing Converter handling for full class name=org.postgresql.util.PGobject, simple name=PGobject".
```

so I returned back this casting.

I tried to remove type in pipeline but results were the same.

I tried to set `nested` type in pipeline but records didn't show in the index.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You should migrate your field from **text** to **keyword**.

Each new word in that case will be a part of an array.

For example:

[image]

In the document it will look like

```
{                   
  "warnings": [ "CARDHOLDER_INVALID", "WEAK_PASSWORD"]
}
```

To actually migrate your field to new type you should to use reindex

I will add guide just in case
https://opster.com/guides/elasticsearch/data-architecture/elasticsearch-change-field-type/